# convert MFC's CString to int for both ASCII and UNICODE

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, ascii, c-strings

Converting `CString` to an `int` in ASCII mode is as simple as

```
CString s("123");
int n = atoi(s);
```

However that doesn't work for projects in UNICODE mode as `CString` becomes a wide-char string.

How do I write my code to cover both ASCII and UNICODE modes without extra `if` statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there's a `_ttoi()` available just for that purpose:

```
CString s( _T("123") );
int n = _ttoi(s);
```

This works for both modes with no extra effort.

If you need to convert hexadecimal (or other-base) numbers you can resort to a more generic `strtol()` variant:

```
CString s( _T("0xFA3") );
int n = _tcstol(s, nullptr, 16);
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a special version of `CString` that uses multibyte characters even if your build is specified for wide characters - `CStringA`. It will also convert from wide characters automatically.

```
CString s(_T("123"));
CStringA sa = s;
int n = atoi(sa);
```

There's a corresponding `CStringW` that only uses wide characters.

Comment: I specifically wanted to avoid any sort of double-coding. So no `CStringA` vs. `CStringW`, no-no-no. In addition to that not all wide-char strings are convertible to ASCII without a proper `locale` and though my short example showed a simplified text the strings are often coming from tokenizing a wide range of inputs and I don't want to debug UNICODE issues, TBH.

Comment: @YePhIcK **1.** If you have additional constraints, they should have been part of the question originally. **2.** Since `atoi` can't process any characters except the digits, it doesn't matter what Unicode characters exist in the original string.

Comment: I agree with both of your points. However my point w.r.t. #2 was that you can't simply assume the `CStringA` would convert from UNICODE with no problems

Comment: I thought I was quite clear on the "no `if`s" constraint: *"How do I write my code to cover both ASCII and UNICODE modes without extra if statements?"*. Should I have worded that differently? Let me know.

Comment: @YePhIcK I don't see any `if` statements in my answer.

Comment: I read the choice between using a `CStringA` and `CStringW` as an `if` statement